# Proof of dense and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I need help with this proofs:

Let $$ f,g\: : \: (X,d)\to(Y,d)$$ continuous functions.

Prove that $$S=\{x\epsilon X \:\mid\:f(x)=g(x)\}$$ is closed on X.

Prove that if $$f(x)=g(x) \quad\forall x \:\epsilon\: T$$

where $T\subset X$ is dense, then $f\:\&\:g$ are the same function.

For the first proof I was thinking something like, if $f(x),g(x)$ are continuous then $$h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$$ is continuous too, so I was thinking I should prove that $$X-S=\{x\epsilon X \:\mid\:h(x)\not= 0\}$$ is an open set, but I'm stuck here.

For the second proof, I have no ideas, suggestions? Anyone?

Comment: It's not correct to use that $h(x)\neq 0$ because you don't know what is meant by $0$ in an arbitrary metric space.

Comment: If they are real valued then you can definitely use

Answer (score 1):

$S=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ .to show that $S^c$ is open .

Let $a\in S^c\implies f(a)\neq g(a)$ .Let $d(f(a),g(a))=r$.

Since $Y$ is Hausdorff so $\exists r>0$ such that $B(f(a),\frac{r}{4})\cap B(g(a),\frac{r}{4})=\emptyset$.

Since $f,g$ are continuous then $\exists \delta_1,\delta _2>0$ such that $f(B(a,\delta _1))\subseteq B(f(a),\frac{r}{4})$ and $f(B(a,\delta _2))\subseteq(B(g(a),\frac{r}{4})$.

Take $\delta =\min\{\delta_1,\delta _2\}>0$

Then you can readily check that $a\in B(a,\delta )\subseteq S^c$.

Regarding the second part: $T\subseteq S\implies \overline{T}\subseteq \overline {S}\implies X\subseteq S$ since $S$ is closed and $T$ is dense .

Comment: Regarding the first question you can see from learnmore's proof that X is any topological space and Y is a Hausdorff space and if f,g are continuous from X to Y, then $\{p\in X : f(p)=g(p)\}$  is closed in X

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, choose a point $y \in X - S$. If $h(y) \neq 0$, then isn't $h$ non-zero on a neighborhood of $y$ since $h$ is continuous? What would this imply about the set $X - S$?

For the second question, you can proceed by contradiction: Suppose that there is a point $x_0 \in X: f(x_0) \neq g(x_0)$. Since $T$ is dense in $X$, we may choose a sequence $\{t_i\}$ of points in $T$ that converge to $x_0$. Since f and g are continuous, the sequences $f(t_i)$ and $g(t_i)$ must converge to $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$, respectively. Do you think you can finish it off?

Comment: Just as an aside, you don't need to proceed by contradiction at all. Just let $x_0\in X$  be any point; the rest proceeds as you have it... and as the OP will finish it :)

Comment: @BrianO I just realized that when I was finishing the proof, thank you both!

Comment: @frl93 Good going:) You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$ is a sequence in $S$ that converges to $a\in X,$ then by the continuity of $f,g$ we have $g(a) = \lim g(x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = f(a).$ Thus $a\in S,$ proving $S$ is closed in $X.$